# Unable to multiply the part along the same axis as rotate in SolidWorks

Tags: solidworks

I am trying to multiply part with `Linera Pattern` and have each instance rotated by 180 degrees. Unfortunately, I can't specify the same axis for both rotation and copying. It says

```
The selection is not parallel to `Direction 1`
```

But how it can be non-parallel, if it is the very same axis?

[image]

Comment: Select the axis for rotation, and a plane for the direction. Are you patterning bodies, rather than features?